# App script appengine tutorial using Go

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-apps-script

On the tutorial for Apps Script/Appengine:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/appengine

When trying to run `google_appengine/dev_appserver.py google-apps-script/` the response is:

```
WARNING  2012-09-06 14:56:33,570 rdbms_mysqldb.py:74] The rdbms API is not available because the MySQLdb library could not be loaded.
INFO     2012-09-06 14:56:33,840 appengine_rpc.py:163] Server: appengine.google.com
CRITICAL 2012-09-06 14:56:33,842 appcfg.py:561] The api_version specified in app.yaml (1) is not supported by this release of the SDK.  The supported api_versions are ['3', 'go1'].
```

I have tried the following app.yaml, but it doesn't work.

```
application: google-apps-script-tutorial
version: 1
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /*
  script: _go_app
```

Also with `- url: /rpc` and it doesn't work.  Since the code is Python is it possible to get App script and Go linked up in app engine?

Comment: Can you post the exact error messages you are getting for your different configurations? Also, please format both the error messages and the configuration.

Comment: Are you using the Go or the Python SDK?

Comment: What is the version of the SDK? (`/path/to/appengine-sdk/go version`)

Comment: I am trying to use the GO SDK, which doesn't work.

Comment: proppy, I am trying to use the GO SDK, which doesn't work. lazy1 My  google_appengine VERSION file contians this:  release: "1.7.1" timestamp: 1342569089 api_versions: ['3','go1']

Answer (score 0):

The code for that tutorial is in Python and Javascript.  If you want to use the go runtime, you will have to rewrite the Python portion in Go.

Answer (score 0):

That example demonstrates the use of a [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) frontend with a [Google App Engine (GAE)](https://developers.google.com/appengine/) backend written in [Python](http://python.org/). GAE currently runs apps written in [Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/), [Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/), [Go](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/) and [PHP](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/).

That particular Python backend accepts and produces messages in [JSON format](http://www.json.org/). Therefore, to link Apps Script and Go similarly, using GAE or not, you would need to replicate the functionality of the Python backend using, probably, the [net/http](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) library and the [encoding/json](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) library.

For examples of using these libraries together, have a look at [this](http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go), [this](http://golang.org/doc/articles/json_and_go.html) and [this](http://nesv.blogspot.com.au/2012/09/super-easy-json-http-responses-in-go.html).

For examples on using Go with GAE, have a look at [this](http://blog.golang.org/the-app-engine-sdk-and-workspaces-gopath) and [this](https://gist.github.com/chrishamant/1075842).

Hope that helps.